# accessing iterator to string (showing undefined behaviour)

Tags: c++, string, iterator

Input : 4

```
    aabc
```

output : throwing exception

According to me I have added only one char to cur and cur.end() will point to
next to that char that is end of string ,if am doing like this --cur.end()
then how why I am not able to access that ?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    string s;
    cin >> n >> s;
    string cur;
    int i = 1;
    cur += s[0];
    cout << cur[*(--cur.end())];

}
```

Comment: Dereferencing `cur.end()`, let alone `--cur.end()`, is not guaranteed to give a value that can be used as a valid array index in `cur`.   The behaviour of `curr[*(--cur.end())]` is therefore undefined, unless `s[0]` happens to give a between `0` and `cur.size()-1`.

Comment: This code `cur[*(--cur.end())]` in your case and assuming you hace ASCII encoding is equal to `cur[97]` because ASCII code for `a` is 97. So it fails because your string is shorter than 98 symbols.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: But same thing works in a vector well (that is if we try to dereference like above @Peter

Comment: I am talking about integer,I have never tried for char but with integers it works always @Slava

Comment: @akacodes121 - you're just getting lucky - or unlucky, depending on how you look at it.   Unless the last element you're adding is a value in the correct range, your approach gives undefined behaviour.   Thst's equally true for a vector or a string.    One nasty feature of undefined behaviour is that it can sometimes SEEM to function correctly - a crash is not a guaranteed result of undefined behaviour, but lack of a crash doesn't been the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: I did not ask what you are talking about, I am asking what you are trying to achieve by this code, because in current state it looks like meaningless random set  of statements. And I do not know what you are trying to achieve with integer either, even if it always works, which I doubt, but we cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
cout << cur[*(--cur.end())];
```

is evil and intricate. With the input you posted, `cur` holds one character by

```
cur += s[0];
```

as `s` is `"aabc"`, and you add the first `char` to `cur`. Then, `--cur.end()` (which should be replaced by `std::prev(cur.end())` or `cur.crbegin()` anyhow) is an iterator to the first character of `cur`, which is `a`. Derferencing the iterator hence yields `a`, which is then used as an argument to `std::string::operator[]`. This function accepts a `std::size_t`, and as the language permits it, `char` is implicitly converted to a `std::size_t`. Try this out:

```
std::cout << std::size_t{'a'} << "\n";
```

and revise the indexing in the last line you posted. It's an out of bounds access.

Comment: But same thing works in a vector well (that is if we try to dereference like above )

Comment: "But same thing works in a vector" if you store `\0` as the only character in `cur` it would work too in this case. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @lubgr  no I am talking about integer,I have never tried for char but with integers it works always

Comment: @akacodes121 What are the values of the integers? How big is your vector?